# Backtick Vs. Single Quote in SQL?

Tags: sql

In SQL, when do you use a backtick ` and a single quote '?

This issue stumped me as I'm learning SQL. Luckily I used a SQL editor and figured it out. I would've never thought of the single quote as being the issue in my code...LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Backtick used in table field, single quote used in field's value.

for example:

```
select `usage` from sys_application where name = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL by default backticks (`) are used to delimit identifiers - names of columns and tables for example. Standard SQL and most other DBMSs use double quotes (") for quoting identifiers. In MySQL you have to use the ANSI_QUOTES mode to allow the use of double quoted identifiers.

MySQL and other SQL DBMSs all use single quotes (') for quoting strings.